# Is KeyGenerator thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, cryptography, thread-safety

I am wondering if I can instantiate the [javax.crypto.KeyGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html) only once and then use this instance in a multithread environment.

Its JavaDoc documentation does not say anything about its thread-safeness. Or it will be better to use a `ThreadLocal<KeyGenerator>` approach?

**UPDATE:** A related question is [Is SecureRandom thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461568/is-securerandom-thread-safe)
While the JavaDoc doesn't state that class is thread safe, the community still found the decision that it **is** thread-safe what is quite important from the practical point of view. I would like to know the same for the KeyProvider.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688609/is-java-security-module-keygenerator-thread-safe-if-not-then-how-to-fix-it

Comment: @assylias I saw that question. Besides the fact that it doesn't provide any useful answer, the question itself is very vague and is related more to that specific problem with particular scala code.

Comment: I think you are misreading the SecureRandom answer. If the documentation does not say it is thread safe then it is a bug to assume it is.

Comment: @JamesKPolk The bug is that it is not marked as it ThreadSafe, while in fact it is (if we are talking about SecureRandom)

Comment: @JamesKPolk: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6498354

Comment: There's no reason to assume that's a bug. The fact that a given implementation is thread-safe is not a guarantee that the next version will be. The only guarantees are what is in the Javadocs.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I agree with you, and I would rather consider it as non-thread-safe. But community says that in fact it *is* thread safe.

Comment: The community does not say that, one user, @erickson, says that (wrongly). The other users note that the *current implementation* is thread-safe. As I said, it is a bug to rely on the such implementation-specific behaviors.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I buy your point of view. It can be one of the accepted answers.

Comment: What 'the community' says is irrelevant. The only relevant source is the official documentation.

Comment: @EJP I agree with you on 100%. That's what is said in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" as far as I remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the documentation explicitly guarantees thread-safety then **treat anything as if it is not thread-safe**.

You're right this philosophy is hardly helpful with the scarcity of thread-safety documentation... But without the documentation guaranteeing thread-safety then you simply can't assume something is *or will continue to be* thread-safe.

---

*Here's some research into the actual implementation of `KeyGenerator` and why we can't assume that it's thread safe*

I found [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.java#KeyGenerator.generateKey%28%29) and at first glance it would seem like the current implementation is thread safe. However, *even if we were to assume this implementation were to never change*, it makes calls to `Security Providers` which could be any implementation of their own and also have no guarantee of being thread-safe since the documentation says nothing about it.

---

*Summary of the source:*

Calls to `generateKey()` use a "Key Generator Service Provider" calling `KeyGeneratorSpi.engineGenerateKey()` *(which could be thread-unsafe)* to generate the `SecretKey`.

If you constructed the `KeyGenerator` with a specific provider then it will use that specific provider to generate the key.

If you did not construct `KeyGenerator` with a specific provider then `nextSpi()` will iterate (thread-safely) through the JVMs list of available providers and try to generate the key until one works or you run out of providers..

---

**The main point is documentation**... If the documentation says nothing about thread-safety then any current implementer or an update to the current implementation might not be thread safe.

So you simply cannot assume or depend on any thread safety from `KeyGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this approach. But it doesn't work in practical purposes. Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461568/is-securerandom-thread-safe

Comment: @Andremoniy Updated my response.

Comment: Your answer would be perfect and definitely accepted if you provide particular peace of its source code which is **not** thread safe. That would be an evidence of its non-thread-safety.

Comment: @Andremoniy working on it, unfortunately byte code is all I have to work with.

Comment: That was an issue. What am I looking for is an evidence of such thread-unsafety. Unfortunately your current answer doesn't bring any value, as this kind of approach (I mean what you suggest - if it is not marked as thread-safe consider it as non-thread-safe) is known for me and everyone.

Comment: I've removed my downvote in appreciation of your efforts. But it is still not convincing for me, I am sorry. Let's wait for another reactions.

Comment: @Andremoniy I looked further into it, it's still pretty iffy.

Comment: In my opinion, the answer in that thread about SecureRandom is incorrect, and this answer is correct.

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer, but you did too much work! Your original shorter answer was correct. The fact that current implementations may or may not be thread-safe is mostly irrelevant. The implementation can change tomorrow and the only behavior guarantees are those given in the Javadocs.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Exactly, that's an issue especially in regards to `KeyGeneratorSpi` which could really be anything...

Comment: @Andremoniy The whole point of this correct answer is that you need evidence of thread *safety*, and in the *documentation,* and that you should not assume it unless you find it.

Comment: If the very @EJP accepts the answer, I have no other way than accept it as well.

Comment: @EJP Yep, that is exactly the point of this answer. The documentation for `KeyGeneratorSpi.engineGenerateKey()` has no thread-safety requirements therefore the thread-safety of `KeyGenerator`s methods is really a moot point.